# Conditionally apply SSE-S3 (AES256) or KMS with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In my s3.tf file I have resource definitions for each S3 bucket, i.e.,

```
    "my-bucket-1" = {
      server_side_encryption_kms_keys = [aws_kms_key.kms_keys["default-key"].arn]
      tags                            = { Function = "A Function" }
    }
```

After the resource definitions I have the following block to apply the encryption to each bucket as defined above.

```
dynamic "server_side_encryption_configuration" {
    for_each = try(each.value.server_side_encryption_kms_keys, [])

    content {
      rule {
        apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
          kms_master_key_id = server_side_encryption_configuration.value
          sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to keep this functionality to apply KMS encryption to buckets that have `server_side_encryption_kms_keys = [aws_kms_key.kms_keys["default-key"].arn]`

However I also want to be able to specify that the bucket should be instead be encrypted with SSE-S3 (AES256) in the resource definition, by means of something like the following:

```
    "my-bucket-2" = {
      server_side_encryption_sse_s3   = true
      tags                            = { Function = "A Function" }
    }
```

I have reviewed the docs at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.75.1/docs/resources/s3_bucket#sse_algorithm but I cannot figure out how to implement both scenarios.

Do I need to modify the existing dynamic block? If so, how? Add a new one? What should that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually asked for was for the default to be SSE-S3 with the AES-256 cipher. As recommended, you would need to specify that as the default instead of no KMS key encryption for the cipher algorithm. You could then update the block's behavior according to the altered default. Since this no longer requires the dynamic optional block design pattern because there are default argument values, the config could be updated where the local is now:

```
"my-bucket-1" = {
  server_side_encryption_kms_key = aws_kms_key.kms_keys["default-key"].arn # notice de-pluraled and now string type
  tags                           = { Function = "A Function" }
}
```

and the block:

```
server_side_encryption_configuration {
  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = try(each.value.server_side_encryption_kms_key, null)
      sse_algorithm     = can(each.value.server_side_encryption_kms_key) ? "aws:kms" : "AES256"
    }
  }
}
```

Also consider updating the config to utilize the updated API form with the [new resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.75.1/docs/resources/s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration).

Comment: bless you, oh wise one

Comment: @yipyip Feel free email me an error message if Terraform or the AWS API barfs on the change.